# Сообщение каждые 10 секунд

Tags: java, android, время

Как выводить сообщение на тосте каждые 10 секунд?

```
public class Primer extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;

    private TextView timerValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.primer);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int sec = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int min = sec / 60;
            sec = sec % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + min + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", sec) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

            ToastUtils.ToastShort(Primer.this, sec + " SECOND");
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);

        }

    }

}
```

Не работает, подскажите!

Comment: я так понял вам нужно, что бы текущий таймер отсчитывал миллисекунды и при этом еще каждую 10 секунду создавал тост?

Comment: Да).............

Comment: в таком случае верните назад customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);... Пока кратко, добавьте глобальную переменную на счетчик для остатка в секундах, и проверку если остаток глобальный счетчик < текущего, вывести тост, суть в том что остаток идет 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 , и когда 0<9 (текущий остаток < глобольного) будет 10 секунд. и в вывести тост.... Я же поехал домой, если у вас получиться , оставьте комментарий, иначе я оформлю как пример кодом, но вечером )

Comment: я исправил свой ответ, посмотрите возможный пример, если поможет то ок, если нет то дома проверю его.

Comment: Не помогло!((((

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте глобальную переменную для остатка в секундах

```
private int mCurrentSec;
```

и в `Runnable` добавьте в конец код

```
if (sec % 10 <= mCurrentSec){
ToastUtils.ToastShort(Primer.this, sec + " 10 SECOND");
}
mCurrentSec = sec % 10;
```

не забудьте вернуть `customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);`

Писал в спешке, надеюсь поможет

Comment: У вас каждую секунду на тосте показывает, как сделать так чтобы показывал только каждые 10 сек?

Comment: Использовать интервал `10000` вместо `1000` :)

Comment: Да укажите 10000 вместо 1000, ошибка копипаста )...

Comment: да нееее! Теперь он просто тост выводит. Но таймер не идет...(

Comment: Как поставили задачу, так и решили ;)

Comment: @Chaynik, подправить создание `Handler` с параметром `Context.getMainLooper()` и будет ответ на 120% корретным.

Comment: Да нет, у ему нужно условие при котором с текущем кодом, но каждую 10 секунду будет выводится Тост )) (нужен доп счетчик с условием)